# how to restrict your app in light mode when Device is in Dark Mode for IOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, macos-darkmode

in your app Delegate. Just go to the func:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
     return true
}
```

Any suggestions....

Answer (score 5):

open info.plist as a source code and add this:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the `info.plist`:

key: `UIUserInterfaceStyle`

string: `Light`

Answer (score 0):

Edit `AppDelegate` with follwing code.

```
func application(_application:UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
     return true
}
```